# basic web2py issue: how to test a web2py package?

Tags: web2py

The package I downloaded is not in .w2p form. It is a folder with different files in it. And I cannot 'install/upload' the folder onto the web2py server. So how can I convert the folder into a w2p file? Or how can I test it locally?

Comment: What is the package and where did you get it? Is it intended to be a full app, or something you include in an existing app?

Comment: It's a full app, a website. It's the folder with all the correct files in it. But I thought we need to convert it into a w2p file to upload it to test it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert to a .w2p file in order to install an app. All you have to do is create a folder inside the `/web2py/applications` folder, and then place all the folders/files of the app inside that new folder. For example, if you want the new app to be named "myapp", create a `/web2py/applications/myapp` folder, and place all the app folders/files (i.e., /controllers, /models, /views, etc) in that folder.

If for some reason you can't easily upload the app files to the server (i.e., no FTP access) and you must rely on the web2py admin app to install applications, you can manually create your own .w2p file. The .w2p file is just a .tar.gz file that has been given a .w2p file, so all you have to do is tar and then gzip the set of folders/files and give the resulting archive a .w2p extension. Then install via the admin app as usual.

Alternatively, if you can run web2py on your local machine, you can simply copy the files into an app folder on your local machine, and then use the admin app on the local machine to pack the app, which will create a .w2p file. There are standalone web2py binaries for Windows and Mac, so it should be easy to run a local copy, even if you don't have Python installed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try the .tar.gz, since I don't have a web2py folder on my mac. It's just an app, no other files.